# Spacing lines in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I need to explain two different elements in two different lines of an equation in math mode. I'm using this piece of code:

```
\begin{align*}
h(z)=0 &\Leftrightarrow \sinh\frac{1}{z}=0 \markno{\Leftrightarrow}{According to ...} \frac{2}{z} = 2\pi i n  \\&\marknoup{\Leftrightarrow}{$n$ is whole} z = \frac{i}{\pi n}
\end{align*}
```

(I'm shortening to make it clearer)

I'm using these macros:

```
\newcommand\markno[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{\,}c@{\,}} #1 \\ \downarrow \\ \makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize #2} \end{array}}
\newcommand\marknoup[2]{\begin{array}[b]{@{\,}c@{\,}} \makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize #2}\\ \uparrow \\ #1 \end{array}}
```

The thing is, that LaTeX automatically spaces the lines, so that the "According two" is above (in height) "n is whole". I'm using two different arrows exactly to avoid that; I want them to overlap in height, in order to save space.

I tried using `\vspace`, but for some reason it doesn't work well for me.

Comment: Write ``\\[-16pt]`` instead of ``\\`` in the `align*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually adjust the space between the lines in an `align` environment by adding an optional argument after the line end; e.g. `\\[-5mm]` instead of just `\\`. You could also try using `\smash` (see page 55 of the [Not So Short Introduction](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english), or sections 2 & 3 of [A complement to \smash, \llap, and \rlap](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/) for details).

Comment: Thanks, it works. As for `\smash`, in the manual they use it in an inline equation. Can it be used in an `align` environment as well?

Comment: Yes. I have added a reference to a document that describes `\smash` in more detail.